# POP_OS OVERLAPPING WINDOWS

Tags: linux

I have been having difficulty overlapping windows, like literally it will automatically divide into halves like left half the original window and the right half the new window.... Anyone wants to help this young man

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is relevant.
New Pop_OS 20.10 has introduced Stacking.
Stacking is activated by (Super+S)
What you are looking for is a proper Tiling, by default you can activate automatic with `Super+Y` (you can then resize as you want) or `Super+G` to activate deactivate it.
Once you have activated this you can also activate the new stacking feature  `Super+S`

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Pop!_OS for couple of months & I've switched to it for mentioned autotiling feature. Just activate it once, maybe from GUI, & forget.

E.g. you have one window. Then open another one, e.g. text editor.

First window **automatically** goes to the *left half*, and second one automatically goes to the *right half*.

By the way, Pop!_OS *is* essentially Ubuntu, I mean Pop!_OS is on top of Ubuntu as Ubuntu is on top of Debian.

Thanks.